# Tensorflow logging in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, logging, tensorflow, console

I'm using TensorFlowSharp in my net application. When tensorflow dll is called, the stdout of the dll is printed out to the Visual Studio debug console with logging info like "creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> ...".
I'd like to redirect the tensorflow dll logging info to a net control like a listview or something like.
I tried to catch the console output with:

```
hconsole = new HConsole(); [<== HConsole is a TextWriter]
Console.SetOut(hconsole);
```

or appending a tracelistener to my app. Nothing seems to work: only my "Console.Write" is redirected to the console, not the output of the tensorflow dll. Starting my app as a Console App, print the tensorflow stdoutput to the console.
Any idea?

Comment: Does [`Console.SetError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.seterror(v=vs.110).aspx) work? TensorFlow sends that Session setup output to stderr rather than stdout.

Comment: @AllenLavoie Console.SetError doesn't work either..